# MSTest Unit Test for range attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

What is the easiest way to test that a range attribute is working? e.g. if FirstName is above 20 chars then it will throw an error

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot exceed 20 characters. ")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

My code currently which fails:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
public void TestFirstNameLength()
{
    UserData user1 = new UserData() { FirstName = "JohnJohnJohnJohnJohnJohn", SecondName = "Smith", Age = 20, HeightCM = 175, WeightKG = 85 };
}
```

Comment: try  if ``user1.FirstName.length > 20`` then throw an exception.

Comment: thanks a lot @Sajid